# Arduino UNOでNEO PIXELのLEDを1000個光らせたい

Tags: arduino

ArduinoUNOでNEO PIXELのLEDを1000個光らせようと思っています。
（https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/1399/）

電源周りなどは問題ないのですが、
どうしても600個くらいで信号が送れなくなってしまいます。

プログラムとしては、

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define PIN 6
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(1000, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
     strip.begin();
     strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
      for (int i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
           strip.setPixelColor(i, 150, 150, 150);
      }
      strip.show();
}
```

以上のような感じで特にデフォルトからいじっていないのですが、

```
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(1000, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
```

の数値を1000だと光らず、600くらいだと光るという感じです。
Arduinoを2個に分けてLED500個ずつだと光るので、LEDや電源の問題ではなさそうです。

わかる方いらっしゃったら参考意見いただけますと有難いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

http://hackaday.com/2014/05/19/driving-1000-neopixels-with-1k-of-arduino-ram/

ここに似たケースが書いてありました。
RAM容量などが影響するようなことが書いてありますので、このサイトと同じようなトリックを使えばドライブさせることができるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 良い回答にするためには、リンクのみだけでなく、リンク先に記載されている1例でも対処方法を回答内に記載すると分かりやすくて良いです。[ヘルプセンター＞回答にあたって＞リンクの文脈を提示する](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: すごい。まさにこれですね。ありがとうございます！！